# Eclipse with Flex plugin: IntelliSense does not Show Protected Methods

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, intellisense

I installed Eclipse with Flex plugin.  And I found in my current workspace, IntelliSense can only show the public methods, it cannot show me the protected methods (but it can compile and the app runs well).

However, in other workspaces, it works well.

If I create a new workspace, it's the same, that the IntelliSense can only show me the public methods, not protected methods.

What happened?

Thanks.

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify where you are trying to access protected methods, but for the moment I'll assume in the same component that defines the protected methods.

A lot of odd issues like this are resolved by cleaning the work space.  You can do that by launching Eclipse with the '-clean' argument.

If that doesn't work, I have heard of people re-creating projects or even work spaces to have odd problems magically go away.  The fact that this does not solve the issue for you makes me wonder what you're trying to access and where.

Protected methods will only show up if you're accessing the class that defines that method or one of it's subclasses.  Protected methods on "Component A" won't be accessible in classes that create instance of "Component A" or in children of "Component A".  Or in parents of "Component A"

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Definitely, I know where to use the protected methods, in a subclass, I was trying to override a protected method in it's super class, such as UIComponent.commitProperties().  In other workspaces I created before, the IntelliSense works fine, but it does not work in the current workspace and newly created workspaces.  And as I said in the Question, though IntelliSense does work, it compiles and runs well.

Comment: @Peter Lee I thougt the whole basis of your question was that intellisense didn't work for protected methods. But, now you are saying it does work? I'm confused about what exactly is working and what is not.

Comment: @? now I'm confused.  I think I made myself very clear that, you are right, the basis of my question is that the IntelliSense does NOT work for protected methods in my current workspace and newly created workspaces, but it (IntelliSense) DOES work in some old workspaces.  As I said before clearly that, even the IntelliSense does not work in my current workspace, the code can still compile and run well.

Comment: @PEter Lee I think I read your previous post wrong, mistaking a comma for a period.  My bad; nevermind.  I've seen intellisense go wockey before, but never past an eclipse restart.

Comment: @Flextras.com,  thank you.  My IntelliSense goes wrong definitely.  and I just don't know how to repair it.  I tried restarting, creating new workspace, but no luck.